# Windows 7 application hangs

Tags: c++, windows, window, gdi+, gdi

I am learning to develop GUI's using GDI/GDI+ it was all wonderful on Win XP, but on Win 7 my window gets "AppHangb1" after it runs for 10-20 secs and i click with mouse on it.
I dont understand the problem.

Here is my WndProc code:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {

    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_PAINT:

        hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

        // TODO: Add any drawing code here...

        MyOnPaint(hdc);

        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }


    DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);

    return 0;
}
```

For Win 7 i have to add handling for some additional messages or what ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Generally if you handle a message you are not supposed to pass it on to DefWindowProc.  I'm guessing you are getting endless WM_PAINT messages or something.  Try just returning 0 from WM_PAINT.

Comment: You're calling DefWindowProc() after your switch block. Usually you would only call it for messages you have not handled (as you have done in the default case). You should return a value from your handlers, not all of them would be 0. Another big difference between XP and 7 is the desktop window manager. If you don't process window messages for something like 5 seconds Windows assumes your application has hung.

Comment: Can i increase that 5 secs to higher value ?